# Putting a multiprocessing.Queue in a multiprocessing.Queue explodes

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, multiprocessing

The following code throws an exception AND prints 123 in both python 2.7 and 3.3.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue

class Pool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = Queue()

p = Pool()
p.q.put(p)
print(123)
```

It's actually some sort of race condition as can be seen here:

```
yuv@yuvpad2:~/$ python3.3 t.py
123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yuv/Downloads/Python-3.3.0/Lib/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 249, in _feed
yuv@yuvpad2:~/$
```

The full error is `RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance` and the traceback doesn't at all explain how/where it happens. The source of the problem is that an object in a Queue can't reference a Queue. My real use case is actually a worker object and a pool object, where a worker reports it finished working to the Pool's `Queue`. So I wanted the worker to send itself back to the worker `Queue`.

The reason I'm not using `Queue.Queue`,although multithreading would work well for my case, is because in Python 2.7 there's a bug which makes queue.get() ignore Ctrl-C which is just annoying.

Is there a way to do this pattern cleanly?

[The real problem code is on codepad](http://codepad.org/JX0lDoeG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the error is complainig about is this:

```
p.q.put(p)
```

Here you're trying to put an object which references a `Queue` into a queue. Queues are used to communicate between processes, and the way this works is by pickling whatever you try to put into it, and unpickling it in the other process - but pickling a `Queue` is not possible, and doesn't even make sense.

That's why when you try to pickle a Queue you get the error you mentioned:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Queue
>>> q = Queue()
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dumps(q)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 77, in __getstate__
    assert_spawning(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 51, in assert_spawning
    ' through inheritance' % type(self).__name__
RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

If you want to use a Queue to share data between processes, a way is doing it like this:

```
class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    def run(self):
        print(self.queue.get())
        ...
```

For more examples you should check the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing)

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are a couple of ways to do this, but without knowing exactly what it is you wan't to do it's hard to recommend one.

I guess the easiest one would be using 2 different queues for this purpose. One for the incoming workers and one fore the finished workers.

Comment: I'm not sure how having 2 queues would help. I.e. I want to queue an object which can add things to the queue. (See the code on codepad)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the traceback isn't showing the problem in your code is that the `multiprocessing.Queue` class starts a background thread, and the exception is being generated in that thread. I get the following traceback...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 266, in _feed
    send(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 77, in __getstate__
    assert_spawning(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 51, in assert_spawning
    ' through inheritance' % type(self).__name__
RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

...which I suspect is being initiated by the line...

```
p.q.put(p)
```

...in which you seem to be putting a `Pool` object containing a `Queue` object into a `Queue`, which is not allowed, hence the error.

It would help to clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve if you want a useful solution.